# How to convert an accented character in an unicode string to its unicode character code using Python?

Tags: python, unicode, character, diacritics, codepoint

Just wonder how to convert a unicode string like `u'é'` to its unicode character code `u'\xe9'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python's [repr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) function:

```
>>> unicode_char = u'é'
>>> repr(unicode_char)
"u'\\xe9'"
```

Answer (score 1):

`ord` will give you the numeric value, but you'll have to convert it into hex:

```
>>> ord(u'é')
233
```

Answer (score 1):

u'é' and u'\xe9' are exactly the same, they are just different representations:

```
>>> u'é' == u'\xe9'
True
```

Comment: The expression evaluate to True in python but False in ipython. Any reason why that happens? Thank you!

Comment: @boativan66: you might have converted it to `u'e\u0301'` during a copy-paste. Try `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'é') == u'\xe9'`